# Storing strings from pointers in Linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

Recently started to practice linked lists. I am aware of the basic algorithm and concept and thought of implementing LL to store a bunch of strings which are input by the user.

But apparently I keep getting `Segmentation fault`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _node{
    char *s;
    struct _node *next;
}
node;

int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    int a = 0;
    char ch;
    char *str = malloc(10);
    do
    {
        printf("\nDude %i:", a);
        fgets(str, 10, stdin);

        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(n == NULL)
        {
            printf("\ninsufficient memory");
            return 1;
        }
        
        if(a == 0)
        {
            strcpy(n->s, str);
            n->next = NULL;
            head = n;
        }

        else
        {
            strcpy(n->s, str);
            n->next = head;
            head = n;
        }
        
        a++;
        printf("\n continue?(y/n): ");
        scanf("\n%c", &ch);
        
    }while(ch == 'y');
    
    for(node *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp -> next)
    {
        printf("\n%s", temp->s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I do understand that my logic/code is flawed somewhere since I am touching memory I should not touch but cannot seem to point out where since it is my first time dealing with linked lists.

Comment: your debugger will tell you **exactly** where the segfault happens. Learning to use a debugger is *not* optional when trying to learn C, and especially memory-reference data structures in C. Voting to close this question as lacking debugging information – but I promise, once you start a debugger on your program, you'll quickly be able to figure out where exactly things go wrong yourself, or you get a much better question to ask here!

Comment: @MarcusMüller is right, just run the code in a debugger, the debugger will certainly tell you which line trigger the segmentation fault.

Comment: ... and it's the exact same thing I would have to do to even try to figure out what your code does. So, doesn't matter whether we or you do that, with the difference that it's your task to become a capable C dev

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help! I will start using the debugger from now on.

Comment: @acertainwanderer it's really made my life soooooo much easier when I learned to do that :)

Comment: I am now looking forward to it now thanks to you Marcus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are `malloc`'ing space for the `struct`, you are only allocating space for the pointer to the string in your `_node` struct. You need to allocate some memory where you store the string and point the pointer `s` to it, before you do the `strcpy`.
i.e.

```
n->s = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
```

Remember that you also need to have a strategy to de-allocate this memory.

As the others hinted, these sort of errors are usually easily caught by looking/debugging with `gdb`. Remember that it's useful to compile with the `-g` flag to get useful debugging info.

Comment: Is allocating some memory only necessary while storing strings?

Comment: Not necessarily. When you are working with pointers (especially inside structures) you need to `malloc`. If you want to statically allocate you need to use values. So for example you could statically allocate some chars by doing something like `char x[10]`. This memory gets freed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Ah, I was referring to how I only need to allocate memory for the pointer to the struct if I am storing numerical values. Since, allocating memory for the struct members separately is something totally new to me until now so I presumed that to be the case with only strings. 
Although seeing how I will need to create a separate block just to deallocate this somewhat special pointer(to me) is making me have second thoughts about using pointers instead of arrays since clearly, the dynamism comes with its trade-offs.

Comment: You can allocate both the struct and the string statically through declaring them in a scope. You would need to change the types of the things you hold in the `struct` from pointers to actual values. This will come with a space cost of course. It's good that you are starting to ask questions about these things. Programming in `C` is all about weighting this sort of questions, and trade offs.

Comment: OH! I cannot believe I forgot about this basic concept- Thank you for keeping up with my foolish doubt and explaining it succinctly. 
So weighing such tradeoffs is advisable too. I see.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you catch a ''Segmentation fault' is because you don't allocate memory for `s` variable of struct `node` before copying actual string: `strcpy(n->s, str)`.
So, allocate memory for `s`:

```
n->s = (char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot write anything into an unallocated space, so you need to call `malloc` for the string in each node.
If the string lengths are fixed, then you can specify the length in the definition of `struct node` to avoid the `malloc` problem.

Also, it is suggested to always `free` the objects that will no longer be referenced.

With a few revisions, the codes below may be helpful:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 10

typedef struct node {
    char str[LEN];
    struct node *next;
} Node;

int main() {
    Node *head = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    char c = 'y';
    while (c == 'y') {
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        printf("Node #%d: ", n);
        scanf(" ");

        /* Store the string directly into the node. */
        fgets(node->str, 10, stdin);
        /* Remove the newline character. */
        node->str[strcspn(node->str, "\n")] = 0;

        node->next = head;
        head = node;
        ++n;
        printf("Continue? (y/N): ");
        scanf("%c", &c);
    };

    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", curr->str);
        Node *temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;

        /* Remember to free the memory. */
        free(temp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Storing the inputs in he node is definitely more effective plus it seems like i totally forgot to free my memory. 
Was it really necessary to remove the newline character though? Though it makes sense if it is needed to do so.